# Fight spam & Validate Inputs in php form

Tags: php

I'd like to improve my form in php to fight spam like url https www, long messages , phone number verification etc. So how can I improve my code to work better?

Thank you!

```
$from = 'noreply@test.com';
$sendTo = 'info@test.com';
$subject = 'New message from contact form';
$fields = array('fname' => 'First name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'tel' => 'Mobile number', 'email' => 'E-mail', 'message' => 'Message',);
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
try
{
if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is empty');
$emailText = "You have a new message from test.com \n=============================\n";
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
if (isset($fields[$key])) {
$emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
}
}
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
        'From: ' . $from,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    );
    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

Comment: Use a captcha to fight spam- such submissions are usually automated and this will catch the vast majority of it